# Open relay python

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import smtplib

message = """From: Test <test@fromdomain.com>
To: test<test@todomain.com>
Subject: SMTP test

This is test

"""

try:
   smtpObj = smtplib.LMTP('exhange.intranet',25)
   smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)         
   print "Successfully sent email"
except SMTPException:
   print "Error: unable to send email"
```

Hello basiclly im testing open relay server and here is question is there other method to send mail without any authetication than LMTP ?How i can implement this with SMTP which paramter is that ?

Sending a mail with only smtp is getting blocked on exhange easyli, there must be included NOT authetication information for exhange to pass it through.

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. To check for an open relay using SMTP, just replace `LMTP` with `SMTP` in the code you list.

Comment: im trying to send email without authetication thats all

Comment: Then you should use `.SMTP()`, not `.LMTP()`. 1) LMTP is for delivery, not sending. 2) LMTP must not be used on port 25.

Answer (score 2):

To use SMTP without authentication, use code like the following:

```
smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('exhange.intranet',25)
smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)         
smtpObj.quit()
```

Comment: Sending a mail with only smtp is getting blocked on exhange easyli, there must be included NOT authetication information for exhange to pass it through.